# Can't set permanent locale settings for bash

Tags: fedora, kde, locale

Fedora 26 with KDE Plasma.

I want to set a locale, but bash (and other programs) seems to ignore my system settings (localectl). Things I tried:

1. Setting via "localectl"
2. Editing /etc/locale.conf
3. Seting via env variable (export LANG="C.utf8") both in /etc/profile and ~/.bash_profile

output of "locale" on newly opened bash:

```
[ ~]$ locale
LANG=C
LC_CTYPE="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_PAPER="C"
LC_NAME="C"
LC_ADDRESS="C"
LC_TELEPHONE="C"
LC_MEASUREMENT="C"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="C"
LC_ALL=
```

Output of localectl

```
[ ~]$ localectl
   System Locale: LANG=C.utf8
       VC Keymap: us
      X11 Layout: us
       X11 Model: pc105+inet
```

Output of locale -a

```
[ ~]$ locale -a
C
C.utf8
POSIX
...
(list goes on)
```

Exporting env variable works, but only for that bash session.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed after editing these files/lines:

```
~/.config/plasma-localerc:LANG=en_US.US-ASCII
~/.config/plasma-locale-settings.sh:export LANG=en_US.US-ASCII
```

Comment: Its written there as # Generated script, do not edit
# Exports language-format specific env vars from startkde.
# This script has been generated from kcmshell5 formats.
# It will automatically be overwritten from there.....what about this.